# Help with powershell error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script to set user password to never expire in Microsoft BPOS. I got the script from Microsoft support but it doesn't work. I could contact them again to support me but I figure stackoverflow would be faster!

The script I got is:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$assigned = Get-MSOnlineUser -credential $cred -enabled | where-object { $_.subscriptionids -ge 0 } | Select-Object displayName, identity

$mailboxes = $assigned | foreach-object { Get-XsHostedExchangeMailbox -SourceServer red001.mail.microsoftonline.com -SourceIdentity $_.identity -SourceAdminCredential 

$cred -SourceDetail Full } | select-object DisplayName, identity

$i = 0;
Foreach($element in $assigned) { 
$mailboxes[$i].displayName = $assigned[$i].displayName;
$mailboxes[$i].identity= $assigned[$i].identity;
Set-MSOnlineUserPasswordNeverExpire -identity $mailboxes[$i].identity -passwordNeverExpire $true -Credential $cred 
$i++; 
}
```

I get prompted for my BPOS credentials (I am an admin) and the error can be seen in the picture:
[Powershell error](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/5204/powershellerror.png)

I am fairly new to powershell so I am not sure how to correct this error, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting bit by formatting in the script try this for the `$mailboxes` assignment:

```
$mailboxes = $assigned | foreach-object { Get-XsHostedExchangeMailbox -SourceServer red001.mail.microsoftonline.com -SourceIdentity $_.identity -SourceAdminCredential $cred -SourceDetail Full } | select-object DisplayName, identity
```

This should be a single line. If it isn't, pop it into notepad, remove the linebreaks and then copy/paste it into your script (or to the prompt).